# problema al obtener el valor data javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo un problema al obtener el data de un dato en javascript

En el html tengo la siguiente linea

```
<span id="internet-compl" class="internet-item" data-precio="${empty elem.extraVl?0:elem.precio }" data-cantidad="1" data-vel="${elem.velocidad}" data-promo="${elem.tienePromoMensual}" data-descpromo="${elem.promo.nombrePromocion}">${elem.titulo}</span>
```

y en el java script tengo lo siguiente

```
        var promo = $("#internet-compl").html($(this).data("promo"));
        console.log(promo);
```

el problema es que en vez de obtener solo el string que asigno al data obtengo todo el elemento HTML como se muestra a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene idea de que estoy haciendo mal

Nota no hay nungun error en la parte de asignar elem.tienePromoMensual que es un objeto que estoy extrayendo con JSTL

Comment: Si solamente quieres capturar el valor de ese atributo ? para que usas .html() y $(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo deseas obtener el valor de uno de sus atributos deberias acceder directamente

```
var promo = $("#internet-compl").data("promo");
console.log(promo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ejecutar de forma directa como te explicaron

```
var promo = $("#internet-compl").data("promo");
console.log(promo);
```

En caso de que manejes otro tag personalizado podrias usar

```
var promoAttr = $("#internet-compl").attr("data-promo");
console.log(promoAttr);
```

Con la diferencia que accediendo con .data() obtendras el valor de acuerdo al tipo de dato si es number o string

Mientras que con .attr() obtendras todo como string

puedes verificarlo con un typeof() dependiendo de lo que necesites